# Установить атрибуты класса импортом из другого файла

Tags: python, ооп

Друзья, привет! Прошу вашей помощи. Есть следующий класс:

```
class MyClass():
    attr_1 = 'a'
    attr_2 = 'b'
    attr_3 = 'c'
    ...
    Целая куча разных атрибутов далее
    ...
```

Решено создать дополнительный файл, где я буду хранить эти атрибуты и подгружать их в свой класс. Код файла и далее новый код класса:

```
#Мой новый файл "file_with_atrr"
attr_1 = 'a'
attr_2 = 'b'
attr_3 = 'c'
...........
final_atr_dict = {'attr_1':attr_1, 
                  'attr_2':attr_2, 
                  'attr_3':attr_3}
```

Код файла с классом:

```
from file_with_atrr import final_art_dict

class MyClass():

    #Гружу атрибуты из файла к себе в класс

    @classmethod
    def load(cls):
        for k,v in final_art_dict.items():
            setattr(cls,k, v)
```

При таком исполнении, мой класс не получает новые атрибуты ровно до тех пор, пока я их не вызову метод в конкретном объекте класса.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вызывать данный метод при созданий объекта класса по умолчанию?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант в лоб:

```
from file_with_atrr import final_atr_dict

class MyClass():
    attr_1 = final_atr_dict['attr_1']
    attr_2 = final_atr_dict['attr_2']
    attr_3 = final_atr_dict['attr_3']
```

Либо то же самое, что вы делаете в методе load, можно просто сделать в основном коде после класса.

```
from file_with_atrr import final_atr_dict

class MyClass():
    pass

for k,v in final_atr_dict.items():
    setattr(MyClass,k, v)
```

Или лучше оставить метод load, но уже после объявления класса один раз его явно дёрнуть:

```
from file_with_atrr import final_atr_dict

class MyClass():

    @classmethod
    def load(cls):
        for k,v in final_atr_dict.items():
            setattr(cls,k, v)

MyClass.load()
```

Либо использовать метаклассы, но для такой простой задачи их использование неоправданно.

UPD: Забыл ещё один очевидный вариант.
В импортируемом файле атрибуты положить не в словарь, а в другой класс. И уже в основном файле наследовать `MyClass` от импортируемого класса.

Comment: Спасибо! Второй вариант мне понравился больше всех

Comment: Пожалуйста. Я добавил в ответ ещё один вариант, возможно, он вам тоже понравится.